# name of the highest a number has to be in a numbering system before flipping to a second digit

Tags: terminology

Name of the highest a number a number has to be in a numbering system when incrementing before flipping it to a second digit and setting the previous digit to 0?

In hex it's `F` (15), in decimal it's `9`, octal it's `7`, in binary it's `1`.

But what is it called?

Comment: Penultimate?${}$

Comment: "one less than the base"? "highest digit"?

Comment: so..the largest single digit? like 9 in base 10?

Comment: Right.  I didn't know if there was a fancier one word term for that.

Comment: "Largest digit" is accurate.